# Is this exchange legitimate?

Tags: exchanges

I was sent a discord message with an invitation to an exchange called [www.doxxwallet.com](https://doxxwallet.com). They offered me 0.21 bitcoin as a joining bonus, and I created the account and according to them do indeed have a wallet with .21 bitcoin. In order to withdraw the bitcoin, I have to transfer to the website 0.006 bitcoin and then I can withdraw the entire balance.

This sounds pretty scammy, but I wanted to see if anyone else had heard of them or had a way to verify that this website is legitimate? I have an image of the message I received below.

[image]

Comment: Definitely a scam

Comment: As always with these things; if someone offers you free money, but you have to pay first to obtain it? It's a scam. Otherwise, they could just deduct the required fees from the money you'd get. It doesn't matter if it's a Nigerian inheritance in USD, or if it's bitcoin. You pay the "fee", and then you never get your promised money.

Comment: "Doxx" sounds like a creepy wallet service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely fake, I got the same exact message saying I won the same amount. Please do not drop $200 to buy yourself .006 btc to get your prize, this oozes sketch in every way possible.

The site isn't even indexed by google, seriously. Google "Doxxwallet.com" and the only result that comes up (at the time of writing) is this thread.

Infact, you can view an IDENTICAL site at https://livebtctrader.com/ and at https://trading4crypto.com/

The only thing changed is the name

edit: holy wow, check out this google query. [https://www.google.com/search?q="Justin+Hance+and+his+team"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Justin+Hance+and+his+team%22). Too many for me to be willing to even count, all identical. This person has been doing this for a while

Comment: It is very likely that Justin Hance is an invented name and that any photos are stock photos of models / actors taken from a photo-agency site like Alamy or Shutterstock or from photos supplied with photo-editing software such as Photoshop etc.

Answer (score 3):

.21 BTC that is ~8000 USD. Who in the world would give out 8000 USD as an incentive for user registration?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a scam. Be sure to change your password if you've used the same password elsewhere, and hopefully you haven't given them any sensitive information.

Comment: No haven't given them any sensitive info. Yeah I figured it seems pretty scammy, is there any way to tell if it's legit or not? $8k is a fair amount of money.

Comment: It's 100% a scam, if they were going to send you free money they would just send it directly rather than ask you to pay a "withdraw fee" or whatever. >$8k USD sign up bonus is a little unreasonable anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

#### It's a scam.

Several things give it away as not being an actual company.
**TL;DR** A lot of things either contradict each other, or make the company feel less formal than it should be, *especially* one that has enough to give away that much

- As others have mentioned, this specific site is a template that's been used countless times
- Nobody is going to give $8k to every single user that joins
- A proper company would use a more proper account name, and fewer emojis - the emojis make it look very informal

  - I'd go so far as to say, a proper company would *not* look for random people on Discord to advertise to - they'd have to have some way to know that you will be a profitable customer. Not to mention that it'd take literally forever to recover that $8k in whatever fees they'd have either way.
- Bad grammar/terms/capitalization/too many exclamation marks also make it sound more informal ("5 day", "crypto project", "Crypto User"/"Giveaway" - these aren't not names so shouldn't have capital)
- "Use the invite once" - any actual company would be able to spend what little time it takes to check if the invite has already been used
- [whois](https://www.whois.com/whois/doxxwallet.com) indicates the domain was registered on Jan 14 (today). Normally you'd purchase the domain first, then spend a couple of days or weeks at the very least ordering/making a website.

  - Add that to the fact that it says in [their about page](https://doxxwallet.com/about): "Our company begins its history from July 2017" (2017, not 2021)
- [Their prices are absolutely insane](https://doxxwallet.com/listing-with-us) - not sure who would pay 3.5BTC and expect to make that back
- It says to "contact online support on the site" if you have questions, however note that there is no way to contact anyone on that site