# Anyone knew about bitnuxt.com?

Tags: exchanges

I have balance in [bitnuxt.com](https://bitnuxt.com) site
0.67 btc, and when I want to withdraw the site says I have to deposit 0.002 btc so that the withdrawal can be done
Anyone know about this site is scam or not ?enter image description here
[image]

The answer,very suspicious. can anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://bitnuxt.com/fee-schedule says:

> | Currency | Depositfee | Withdrawal fee | Min. Deposit | Min. Withdrawal |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | BTC | 0.0005 | 0.0005 | 0.01 | 0.0003 |

Personally, I wouldn't use such a service, but the obnoxious fees are there in plain sight for all prospective customers to read.

Also, importantly, they would deduct that fee from your balance, not ask you to pay it in. This aspect makes it clear that someone is scamming you.

If someone helped you set up this account, you are definitely the victim of a scam

---

Websites with [same claimed founder name](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our+founder+-+Justin+Hance%22)

- bitnuxt com
- bitwire ltd
- issuu com
- bitkindly com
- cryptonexer com
- fastocoin com

and many many others. I think it certain they are *all* scam sites -- or, at best, all but one.

---

Related:

- [Is this exchange legitimate?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101477/13866) (about another "[Justin Hance](https://www.google.com/search?q=Justin+Hance+cryptocurrency)" website)
- [How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/98743/13866) (see 4th point in my answer there)
- [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)
- [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)